# JSON object parsing with PHP in bash

Tags: php, json, bash, parsing

I tried to parse JSON object with PHP in bash.

```
{
    "department": {
        "name": "MyDepartment",
        "emp_no": 10
    }
}
```

And

```
#!/bin/sh
key=department->name
jsonbody=./object.json

value=$(php -r "\$obj = json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents('$jsonbody')));print \$obj->'$key';")
```

I got the error message as below. How can handle JSON object with bash variable?

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in Command line code on line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This solves it:

```
#!/bin/sh
key='department->name' # or key="department->name"
jsonbody=./object.json

value=$(php -r "\$obj = json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents('$jsonbody')));print \$obj->$key;")
# $key, not '$key'

echo $value
```